# Get stats of reused connections with PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

How can I get the **amount of reused connections** from PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager?

It contains the getTotalStats() method that returns a PoolStats, but no information about the amount of reused connections is present.

The PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager has a private instance of CPool which extends AbstractConnPool from httpcomponents-core. When a connection is reused the method getPoolEntryBlocking calls the onReuse(entry) method that could be used for this purpose.

I don't see a way to get this information for monitoring purposes.
Does anyone see another alternative?

Answer (score 1):

If you extend the standard pooling connection manager or decorate it, it should give you an entry point for collection of the needed connection re-use details

```
public class MyPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager extends PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager {

    final AtomicLong reusedCount = new AtomicLong();

    @Override
    protected HttpClientConnection leaseConnection(
            Future<CPoolEntry> future,
            long timeout,
            TimeUnit timeUnit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, ConnectionPoolTimeoutException {
        HttpClientConnection conn = super.leaseConnection(future, timeout, timeUnit);
        if (conn.isOpen()) {
            reusedCount.incrementAndGet();
        }
        return conn;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, @ok2c but I need clarification. I see that the method AbstractConnPool#getPoolEntryBlocking may create a new connection using the ConnFactory. The DefaultBHttpClientConnection#createConnection calls the bind method which says that the connection will be considered opened after the call.
It seems that the new connections will also have the open status and I may count new connections as if they were reused using your snippet.

Comment: @EduardoSilva Newly created connections are not bound to a socket and therefore are considered disconnected (not open).

Comment: The CPoolEntry is not public. This is preventing me to override the method.

Comment: @EduardoSilva I see no reason why one would need to override methods in CPoolEntry just to collect connection re-use stats.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to subclass **ConnectionRequest** and override the *get* method to delegate the execution to a **ConnectionRequest** instance received on the constructor.

Then I override the *requestConnection* from **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager** and wrap the returned **ConnectionRequest** with the subclass created.

If the connection is open then, I increment the stats of the reused connections. Otherwise, I increment the stats of the created connections.

```
public class MonitoredPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager extends PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

    private final AtomicInteger createdConnections = new AtomicInteger();
    private final AtomicInteger reusedConnections = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public ConnectionRequest requestConnection(HttpRoute route, Object state) {
        ConnectionRequest requestConnection = super.requestConnection(route, state);
        return new MonitoredConnectionRequest(requestConnection);
    }
    
    private class MonitoredConnectionRequest implements ConnectionRequest {

        private ConnectionRequest wrapped;

        public MonitoredConnectionRequest(ConnectionRequest requestConnection) {
            this.wrapped = requestConnection;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean cancel() {
            return wrapped.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public HttpClientConnection get(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, ConnectionPoolTimeoutException {
            HttpClientConnection conn = wrapped.get(timeout, timeUnit);
            if (conn.isOpen()) {
                reusedConnections.incrementAndGet();
            } else {
                createdConnections.incrementAndGet();
            }
            return conn;
        }
    }
```